# Trying to search JSON and display matching results to the screen using grunt and angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to search through JSON that I load into a variable using angularJS with grunt. I had my app set up with Yeoman. I have done this type of search before without a server, but now that I am trying to use a server, it won't work for me here. I am getting no errors from Chrome, but when I type in the text entry, nothing is returned. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my view:

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="DatabaseCtrl as result">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchString">
  </div>
  <ul ng-if="searchString" ng-repeat="i in result.json | filter:searchString">
    <li>
      <b>{{i.name}}</b> <br><br>
      Realm: {{i.realm}} <br>
      Description: {{i.description}} <br>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name fourthgruntApp.controller:DatabaseCtrl
 * @description
 * # DatabaseCtrl
 * Controller of the fourthgruntApp
 */
angular.module('fourthgruntApp')
  .controller('DatabaseCtrl', function () {

    this.json = [
            {
                "name": "Temple of Snow",
                "dungeontype": "Temple",
                "alignment": "Neutral Good",
                "size": "Small",
                "agedescriptor": "Millenniums Old",
                "hex": "00000",
                "realm": "Ernst Chase",
                "description": "Temple to the god of Snow. These ancient temples were built long ago by the explorers of the Far Wield when they made their towns and villages. Followers of the gods make pilgrimages to these temples throughout the year."
            },
            {
                "name": "Temple of Memory",
                "dungeontype": "Temple",
                "alignment": "Neutral Good",
                "size": "Meduim",
                "agedescriptor": "Millenniums Old",
                "hex": "08000",
                "realm": "Ernst Chase",
                "description": "Temple to the god of Memory. These ancient temples were built long ago by the explorers of the Far Weald when they made their towns and villages. Followers of the gods make pilgrimages to these temples throughout the year. Upon entering the temple, it's said that one can recall information previously thought to be lost. With enough meditation, some priests of Memory have claimed to be able to tap into the memory of others while in the temple."
            },
            {
                "name": "Temple of Sky",
                "dungeontype": "Temple",
                "alignment": "Neutral Good",
                "size": "Diminutive",
                "agedescriptor": "Millenniums Old",
                "hex": "20000",
                "realm": "Karmswald",
                "description": "Temple to the god of Sky. These ancient temples were built long ago by the explorers of the Far Weald when they made their towns and villages. Followers of the gods make pilgrimages to these temples throughout the year. ",
                "notes": "1. There is a rock near the altar with an engraving that reads “Bow before the holder of the blessed sun, kneel in the glory of the clouds that are carried in it’s arms.”  2. If you commune with the altar here you gain 10 ft of movement speed for 2 days.\n"
            }
        ]
  });
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your ng-app in html,

**`From`**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
```

**`To`**

```
<div ng-app="fourthgruntApp">
```

Also your module should have empty dependencies injected

```
angular.module('fourthgruntApp',[])
```

Also take your div which has **`ng-controller`** common for `ng-repeat` and **`input`** search

```
 <div ng-controller="DatabaseCtrl as result">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchString">
    <ul ng-repeat="i in result.json | filter:searchString">
      <li>
        <b>{{i.name}}</b>
        <br>
        <br> Realm: {{i.realm}}
        <br> Description: {{i.description}}
        <br>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**[DEMO](https://embed.plnkr.co/0PDPSE9mfNmhK1r6rV71/)**

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much!